# Error starting with java and jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm trying to create a Rest application with Jersey using Maven but I always end up having the same errors.

I downloaded the default zip on the Jersey website and set up my jars in the project, but every time I start the application the following error is returned:

```
jul 22, 2017 5:34:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Service] in web application [/com.radarveicular.service] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1271)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:577)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:418)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder.configure(ServiceFinderBinder.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:187)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:187)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Do you have `jersey-common` jar in your classpath ? If not, then add and try again.

Comment: Until now I download the zip on Jersey's Website, wich already have a jersey-common, and added the jars into my project. I need to do anything else?

Comment: Tagging with the REST tag is important, because then people who are watching that tag can see it and you probably would get more answers. Also, javax is not needed here.

Comment: why Javax is not needed? I am a bit confusing now, because on the zip that i downloaded on Jerseys website, it comes within.

Comment: I was trying to create this rest project on a Windows machine and i got this error. Now I follow the same steps on a Ubuntu machine and it works great, but i still not get why this error occurs.

Comment: According to your question, you are using Maven. So why are you manually downloading your dependencies? Please show your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that.. I tried to configure only installing the jars, and then I tried using Maven and either the both ways did't work out. I Follow the same steps to configure the project in a Ubuntu machine and works great. I have no ideia why i'm getting this errors in Windows.